# for loop over sequence, then make string and post via json

Tags: bash, curl, seq

Consider this simple bash script : (I am writing `myurl` as a placeholder for the correct URL; and `myhost` as the placeholder for the correct hostname for privacy here.)

```
for a in `seq 400 450`; do
curl --request POST \
  --url myurl \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Host: myhost' \
  --data '{
"devID": "21010010",
"count": 0,
"fileEnd": 1,
"line": "",
"file": "$a"
}'
done
```

This is rejected as bad request. I want, the output of `seq`, (e.g. the number 410) to be a quote delimated string. Notice the line `"file": "$a"`. If I write `"file": "410"`, this works perfectly, and also for any other file between 400 and 450 - as long as it is surrounded by `""` quotes.

**Question :**

I want, that in each iteration of the loop, the curl request should include the number coming from the `seq` command surrounded by `""`. So the first call should be :

```
curl --request POST \
  --url myurl \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Host: myhost' \
  --data '{
"devID": "21010010",
"count": 0,
"fileEnd": 1,
"line": "",
"file": "400"
}'
```

The next one to be :

```
curl --request POST \
  --url myurl \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Host: myhost' \
  --data '{
"devID": "21010010",
"count": 0,
"fileEnd": 1,
"line": "",
"file": "401"
}'
```

and so on.

How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--data` portion is wrapped in single quotes ...

```
'{"devID": ... "file": "$a"}'
```

... which disables the expansion of variable references inside said single quotes.

Consider:

```
$ a=410
$ echo '"devID": "21010010", "file": "${a}"'
"devID": "21010010", "file": "${a}"              # ${a} not expanded
```

You could wrap the `--data` section in double quotes, but then you need to also escape all of the nested double quotes.

Another idea is to break the `--data` section into 2x sections wrapped in single quotes and place the `${a}` reference between the 2x sections, eg:

```
$ echo '"devID": "21010010", "file": "'${a}'"'   # change "${a}" to "'${a}'"
"devID": "21010010", "file": "410"               # ${a} successfully expanded
```

**NOTE**: There are several posts regarding the difference between single and double quotes, eg, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753)